How to keep/hold UV aspect from square image to non-square?
I made a model and textured it by using 'tiling' method. So now I have a few textures in 1024x1024 size on my model.
Then I decided to optimize my model and merge my textures into one. For example 1024x2048 It looks like that:
.
But when I apply my new material with that non-square image, my UV shells starts to stretch.
There is before and after:


So I can, of course, re-unwrap my model after I apply my new textures in 1024x2048, but maybe there is an another way? How can I add a texture with non-square aspects (1024x2048) and keep my UV like they were before?..
PS: it's a game model.

hello by default the UVs will be proportional to the image proportions, you could make it proportional again but I wonder if the best is not to just scale the UVs in the UV Editor with a SY0.5?
